# Gradle warning in non-gradle project Android Studio 0.4.5

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying out Android Studio 0.4.5, on projects imported from an eclipse workspace, and I keep getting the following error message:

> Gradle files have changed since the last project sync. A project sync
>   may be necessary for the IDE to work properly

It is not a gradle project, but Android Studio seems to think it is. Is this something I can fix?

Comment: Studio automatically converts non gradle projects to gradle projects. Include the project structure after import in question.

Comment: I'm on a Maven Project, I should not get this either. I hope they fix it.

Comment: So you all reckon it's just a bug, and not a mistake I made in configuration?

Comment: Looks like a bug. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Android Studio. This bug has been fixed in [Android Studio 0.4.6](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio046released):

> This is primarily a bug fix release from Android Studio 0.4.5 released five days ago. In particular, the Gradle sync editor notifications should be fixed now

Comment: Fixes by the day. Gotta stay on top of it. Cheers.